# Creating and mailing Excel spreadsheets in Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: excel, windows-phone-8

I am doing WP, which is contain List of data, and I am trying to add those data into excel sheet.
And this sheet will be attach my mail when I send the mail..
I got one dll but this is still give me error when I generate excel sheet and I press Ok then it will work but I am not satisfied with this is there any other option where I can achieve this scenario..

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost - what DLL are you using? What kind of error are you getting?

Second, if you want to send the document in an email (as an attachment), you won't be able to do that with the out-of-the-box [EmailComposeTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adevelop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Instead, you could use the [LiveMailMessage](http://windowsphonegeek.com/marketplace/components/livemailmessage) library:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.Email = "test@email.id";
mailMessage.Password = "somePassword";
mailMessage.AccountType = MailMessage.accountType.MicrosoftAccount;
mailMessage.To = "destination@email.id";
mailMessage.Subject = "Test Subject";
mailMessage.Body = "Test Body";
mailMessage.AddAttachement("/Path/to/Spreadsheet");
mailMessage.Send();
```

Comment: I am using Silverlight.spredsheet but it is giving me error.my problem is I have windows phone data which is display into summary page so this summary page I have to convert into Excel sheet and attach this excel sheet and sent to particular ID.